# Pandas Dataframe, Column of lists, Create column of sets of cumulative lists, and record by record differences

Tags: python, list, pandas, lambda, set

I have a simple dataframe `df` with a column of lists `lists`.  I would like to generate 3 additional columns based on `lists`.

`df` looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
lists={1:[[1]],2:[[1,2,3]],3:[[2,9,7,9]],4:[[2,7,3,5]]}
#create test dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lists,orient='index')
df=df.rename(columns={0:'lists'})
df

          lists
1           [1]
2     [1, 2, 3]
3  [2, 9, 7, 9]
4  [2, 7, 3, 5]
```

I would like `df` to look like this:

```
    lists     cumset        adds    drops
1   [1]       {1}           {1}     {}
2   [1,2,3]   {1,2,3}       {2,3}   {}
3   [2,9,7,9] {1,2,3,7,9}   {7,9}   {3}
4   [2,7,3,5] {1,2,3,5,7,9} {3,5}   {9}
```

Basically I need to figure out how to create `cumset` (some type of apply?, (is there already a pandas function?).  Then for the adds and drops, basically we want to compare the df.lists to the df.lists.shift(), and determine which items are new and which items are missing. maybe something like:

```
df['adds']=df[['lists',df.lists.shift()]].apply(lambda x: {i for i in x.lists if i not in x.lists.shift()}, axis=1)
```

Have fun and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.DataFrame.cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html) to make the cumulative column and make a column with sets instead of lists and use [pandas.DataFrame.shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to make "add" and "drop" columns:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df['cumset'] = df['lists'].cumsum().apply(lambda x: np.unique(x))
df['sets'] = df['lists'].apply(lambda x: set(x))

shifted = df['sets'].shift(1).apply(lambda x: x if not pd.isnull(x) else set())

df['add'] = df['sets'] - shifted
df['drop'] = shifted - df['sets']
df = df.drop('sets', axis=1)

print(df)
#-->Output:
          lists              cumset     add    drop
1           [1]                 [1]     {1}      {}
2     [1, 2, 3]           [1, 2, 3]  {2, 3}      {}
3  [2, 9, 7, 9]     [1, 2, 3, 7, 9]  {9, 7}  {1, 3}
4  [2, 7, 3, 5]  [1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9]  {3, 5}     {9}
```

Comment: excellent and it works.  I think the best solution is a combination of both lukess and @jezreal below.  IMO lukess handling of ['add'] and ['drop'] slightly more pythonic as using the actual df column instand of making a new temp column.  jezreal slightly more pythonic in handling .cumsum without the need for np.unique, and apply(set) instead of using lambda.  lukess slightly better at fixing the nan created from the shift with using 'else set', versus specifically applying to the 0 index.  Great job guys.  Selecting lukess because he was first, but both get upvoted!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [`Series.cumsum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) + [`Series.shift`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.shift.html) + [`Series.iat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.iat.html) and mainly [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) for `set`s:

```
df['cumset'] = df['lists'].cumsum().apply(set)
lists_sets = df['lists'].apply(set)
lists_shifted = lists_sets.shift()
#replace first value - NaN to set
lists_shifted.iat[0] = set()
lists_shifted = lists_shifted.apply(set)
df['add'] = lists_sets - lists_shifted
df['drop'] = lists_shifted - lists_sets
print (df)
          lists              cumset     add    drop
1           [1]                 {1}     {1}      {}
2     [1, 2, 3]           {1, 2, 3}  {2, 3}      {}
3  [2, 9, 7, 9]     {1, 2, 3, 9, 7}  {9, 7}  {1, 3}
4  [2, 7, 3, 5]  {1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9}  {3, 5}     {9}
```

Comment: thx jezreal.  See comments in lukess in the selected solution.  Yours works perfectly though and I upvoted.