# Python Pandas rolling aggregate a column of lists

Tags: python, pandas, list, group-by, pandas-groupby

I have a simple dataframe df with a column of lists `lists`. I would like to generate an additional column based on `lists`.

The `df` looks like:

```
import pandas as pd
lists={1:[[1]],2:[[1,2,3]],3:[[2,9,7,9]],4:[[2,7,3,5]]}
#create test dataframe
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lists,orient='index')
df=df.rename(columns={0:'lists'})
df

          lists
1           [1]
2     [1, 2, 3]
3  [2, 9, 7, 9]
4  [2, 7, 3, 5]
```

I would like `df` to look like this:

```
df
Out[9]: 
          lists                 rolllists
1           [1]                       [1]
2     [1, 2, 3]              [1, 1, 2, 3]
3  [2, 9, 7, 9]     [1, 2, 3, 2, 9, 7, 9]
4  [2, 7, 3, 5]  [2, 9, 7, 9, 2, 7, 3, 5]
```

Basically I want to 'sum'/`append` the rolling 2 lists.  Note that row 1, because I only have 1 list [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501875/pandas-dataframe-column-of-lists-create-column-of-sets-of-cumulative-lists-an), rolllists is that list.  But in row 2, I have 2 lists that I want appended.  Then for row three, append `df[2].lists` and `df[3].lists` etc.  I have worked on similar things before, reference this:[Pandas Dataframe, Column of lists, Create column of sets of cumulative lists, and record by record differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501875/pandas-dataframe-column-of-lists-create-column-of-sets-of-cumulative-lists-an).
In addition, if we can get this part above, then I want to do this in a `groupby` (so the example below would be 1 group for example, so for instance the `df` might look like this in the `groupby`):

```
  Group         lists                 rolllists
1     A           [1]                       [1]
2     A     [1, 2, 3]              [1, 1, 2, 3]
3     A  [2, 9, 7, 9]     [1, 2, 3, 2, 9, 7, 9]
4     A  [2, 7, 3, 5]  [2, 9, 7, 9, 2, 7, 3, 5]
5     B           [1]                       [1]
6     B     [1, 2, 3]              [1, 1, 2, 3]
7     B  [2, 9, 7, 9]     [1, 2, 3, 2, 9, 7, 9]
8     B  [2, 7, 3, 5]  [2, 9, 7, 9, 2, 7, 3, 5]
```

I have tried various things like df.lists.rolling(2).sum() and I get this error:

```
TypeError: cannot handle this type -> object
```

in Pandas 0.24.1 and unfortunatley in Pandas 0.22.0 the command doesn't error, but instead returns the exact same values as in `lists`.  So Looks like newer versions of Pandas can't sum lists? That's a secondary issue.

Love any help!  Have Fun!

Comment: `df.lists.cumsum()` can handle lists, but it doesn't give you a rolling window. Combining lists like this isn't really what Pandas is built for...

Comment: @JoshFriedlander, can you add some detail on why Pandas is not built for this?  I have found it useful for many types of column/row wise data manipulation.  There are many examples of cases where you store lists and want to combine them in some fashion,. Pandas built for data manipulation and time series, and dataframes can hold lists,sets, etc.  the fact that cumsum can do this, it would be nice if rolling could.  maybe a way to take and subtract two offset cumsums?

Comment: Sorry but that's incorrect, because lists are not "first-class citizens" as Pandas values. See Jeff Reback's comment [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/18129#issuecomment-342298867).

Comment: I did read that.  it is unfortunate, as lists are very pythonic, and can handle situations where yo need to process groups of numbers or strings as a whole.  there has to be a way to do this.   even if ugly

Comment: Oh, I'm sure there is *a* way. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can start with

```
import pandas as pd
mylists={1:[[1]],2:[[1,2,3]],3:[[2,9,7,9]],4:[[2,7,3,5]]}
mydf=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(mylists,orient='index')
mydf=mydf.rename(columns={0:'lists'})
mydf = pd.concat([mydf, mydf], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
mydf['group'] = ['A']*4 + ['B']*4

# initialize your new series
mydf['newseries'] = mydf['lists']

# define the function that appends lists overs rows
def append_row_lists(data):
    for i in data.index:
        try: data.loc[i+1, 'newseries'] = data.loc[i, 'lists'] + data.loc[i+1, 'lists']
        except: pass
    return data

# loop over your groups
for gp in mydf.group.unique():
    condition = mydf.group == gp
    mydf[condition] = append_row_lists(mydf[condition])
```

Output

```
          lists Group                 newseries
0           [1]     A                       [1]
1     [1, 2, 3]     A              [1, 1, 2, 3]
2  [2, 9, 7, 9]     A     [1, 2, 3, 2, 9, 7, 9]
3  [2, 7, 3, 5]     A  [2, 9, 7, 9, 2, 7, 3, 5]
4           [1]     B                       [1]
5     [1, 2, 3]     B              [1, 1, 2, 3]
6  [2, 9, 7, 9]     B     [1, 2, 3, 2, 9, 7, 9]
7  [2, 7, 3, 5]     B  [2, 9, 7, 9, 2, 7, 3, 5]
```

Comment: This works.  So if I wanted to "roll" for 7 periods, I would need to continue the additions in the function.  Would love a way to streamline that with a variable.  Can I ask why the 'pass' in the exception?  Can you foresee exceptions or just being careful?  Or is the pass for the 'first case' where there are not the right num of lists to combine?  I am upvoting this now, to see if something else comes along.  It works and I will select as the correct answer if a better solution evades us...

Comment: to understand the `try|except`, delete them from the function and update the function. You will encounter an `indexing` error from `pandas` because the last `indexer` does not exist in the dataframe. So just `pass` if **any** error happens

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
rolllists = [df.lists[1].copy()]
for row in df.iterrows():
    index, values = row
    if index > 1:  # or > 0 if zero-indexed
        rolllists.append(df.loc[index - 1, 'lists'] + values['lists'])
df['rolllists'] = rolllists
```

Or as a slightly more extensible function:

```
lists={1:[[1]],2:[[1,2,3]],3:[[2,9,7,9]],4:[[2,7,3,5]]}
df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(lists,orient='index')
df=df.rename(columns={0:'lists'})

def rolling_lists(df, roll_period=2):
    new_roll, rolllists = [], [df.lists[1].copy()] * (roll_period - 1)
    for row in df.iterrows():
        index, values = row
        if index > roll_period - 1:  # or -2 if zero-indexed
            res = []
            for i in range(index - roll_period, index):
                res.append(df.loc[i + 1, 'lists'])  # or i if 0-indexed
            rolllists.append(res)
    for li in rolllists:
        while isinstance(li[0], list):
            li = [item for sublist in li for item in sublist]  # flatten nested list
        new_roll.append(li)
    df['rolllists'] = new_roll
    return df
```

Easily extensible to `groupby` as well, just wrap it in a function and use `df.apply(rolling_lists)`. You can give any number of rolling rows to use as `roll_period`. Hope this helps!

Comment: does this deal with the roll 'period'?  am i missing something?  ie 2 period roll, or 5?  I think this works exclusively for 2.

Comment: edit my answer to be extensible to `n` roll_periods...check it out

Comment: i am going to try this next.  @j. doe version takes a trmemndous amount of time.

Comment: this version also tookk quite a long time unfortunately.  but works so upvote but gonna give J.Doe the accepted answer because slightly easier IMO.  that said, for what i was trying to do, I created a solution which converted lists to a string, created a giant string as the roll, then converted that string back to a list.  infinitely quicker.  For instance, J.Does solution for my medium size data set took 82 minutes.  My strings back to list took .05 minutes...  Thanks all...