# Python Dataframe Create a rolling aggregate of list column with a window

Tags: python, list, dataframe, window, rolling-computation

I have a df that has a column of lists.

[Python Pandas rolling aggregate a column of lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54650868/python-pandas-rolling-aggregate-a-column-of-lists)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Get some time series data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/timeseries.csv")
input_cols = ['A', 'B']
df['single_input_vector'] = df[input_cols].apply(tuple, axis=1).apply(list)
```

I am wondering if there is a way to create a rolling aggregate of the 'single_input_vector' column for a given window. I looked at the following SO link but it does not provide a way to include a window. In my case, the desired output column for a window of 3 would be:

```
Row1: [[24.68, 164.93]] 
Row2: [[24.68, 164.93], [24.18, 164.89]]
Row3: [[24.68, 164.93], [24.18, 164.89], [23.99, 164.63]] 
Row4: [[24.18, 164.89], [23.99, 164.63], [24.14, 163.92]]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of a more efficient way to do this, so while this does work there may be performance constraints on massive data sets.

We are basically using rolling count to create a start:stop set of slicing indices.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Get some time series data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/timeseries.csv")
input_cols = ['A', 'B']
df['single_input_vector'] = df[input_cols].apply(tuple, axis=1).apply(list)


window = 3

df['len'] = df['A'].rolling(window=window).count()

df['vector_list'] = df.apply(lambda x: df['single_input_vector'][max(0,x.name-(window-1)):int(x.name)+1].values, axis=1)
```